# How to make my spacer work in the fixed header?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a simple header. There are two boxes (DIVs) to be more precise. Both of them are part of the header

```
HEADER
   BOX 1
   BOX 2
```

I want the first box to dissapear as the user scrolls down but keep the second box fixed. The second box which is fixed also shrinks a little bit in height.

The problem is that I want the "Content" heading to be visible right in the moment when the second box shrinks and becomes fixed. However as the user scrolls down more I want the "Content" header to dissapear below the fixed header with the other content as well.

I wanted to solve this using vanilla JavaScript. I suppose the solution for my issue is just a spacer, but I added it and doesn't seem to work.

```js
"use strict";

const header = document.querySelector(".header-main");
const sticky = header.offsetTop;

window.addEventListener("scroll", event => {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("is-sticky");
    header.style.height = "70px";
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("is-sticky");
    header.style.height = "100px";
  }
});
```

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.header-above {
  background: lightseagreen;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100px;
}

.header-main {
  background: #0A246A;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.header-main.is-sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-main.is-sticky + .main {
  padding-top: 120px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fixed-header-plusabove.css">
  <title>Fixed Header Plus Above</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="header-above">
      <div class="header-above-container">
        <p>Header Above Container</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="header-main">
      <div class="header-main-container">
        <p>Header main</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <main>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <script>
      for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        document.write("<p>Some text...</p>");
      }
    </script>
  </main>
  <script src="fixed-header-plusabove.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the spacing idea, could be a solution for you.
You have 2 mistakes in your shown code:

1. `.header-main.is-sticky + .main`

there is no class named main, only the html tag `<main>`

2. with the code line above, even with `<main>`, you won't affect the main element.

If you add a class like `.is-sticky` to the parent class `header.header` you could use ur code line like this:

`header.header.is-sticky + main`

```js
"use strict";

const parentHeader = document.querySelector(".header");
const header = document.querySelector(".header-main");
const sticky = header.offsetTop;

window.addEventListener("scroll", event => {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("is-sticky");
    parentHeader.classList.add("is-sticky");
    header.style.height = "70px";
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("is-sticky");
    parentHeader.classList.remove("is-sticky");
    header.style.height = "100px";
  }
});
```

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.header-above {
  background: lightseagreen;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100px;
}

.header-main {
  background: #0A246A;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.header-main.is-sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

header.header.is-sticky + main {
  padding-top: 120px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
    <div class="header-above">
      <div class="header-above-container">
        <p>Header Above Container</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="header-main">
      <div class="header-main-container">
        <p>Header main</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <main>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <script>
      for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        document.write("<p>Some text...</p>");
      }
    </script>
  </main>
  <script src="fixed-header-plusabove.js"></script>
```